# C++ find method is not const?

Tags: c++, find, constants, stl-algorithm

I've written a method that I'd like to declare as const, but the compiler complains. I traced through and found that this part of the method was causing the difficulty:

```
bool ClassA::MethodA(int x)
{
    bool y = false;
    if(find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), x) != myList.end())
    {
        y = true;
    }
    return y;
}
```

There is more happening in the method than that, but with everything else stripped away, this was the part that didn't allow the method to be const. Why does the stl find algorithm prevent the method from being const? Does it change the list in any way?

Comment: By the way, just do `return find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), x) != myList.end();`. Other than that, it looks fine.

Comment: I don't see anything that would prevent you from making the method const.  What is the specific compiler error you are getting?

Comment: Could you possibly post the compiler error?

Comment: @Gman I was about to say the same thing, but then remembered that Rachel has stripped away code within this method.  Thus, a single return statement would probably not work.

Comment: Sure it uses the standard libraries `find` and not a non-const member function that's called `find`?

Comment: @Shakedown: Yup, forgot about that. I'm with the others: Either find is a member function and `std::find` isn't being used (hm, `using namespace std;` strikes again!) or the error is something else. More code is needed.

Comment: If `std::find` were trying to change something, you would get a compiler error pointing to the line of code inside `std::find` that was. I suppose Mike is right that you must be using a custom container class.

Comment: Could I suggest to rewrite your function in a more efficient way? `bool ClassA::MethodA(int x)
{
    if(find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), x) != myList.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}`

Comment: In general, is there a reason why STL does not require `const_iterators` for a function which does not modify the container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If myList is an object of a custom container type, you could have a problem if its begin() and end() methods don't have a const overload.  Also, assuming perhaps the type of x isn't really int in your code, are you sure there's an equality operator that can operate on a const member of that type?

Comment: Nice detective work. Of course, the answer would have been obvious if @Rachel had just posted the compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your implementation and had no problems with it:

```
class ClassA
{
    vector<int> myList;
public:
    bool MethodA(int x) const;
};

bool ClassA::MethodA(int x) const
{
    bool y = false;
    if (find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), x) != myList.end())
        y = true;

    return y;
}
```

When you tried to make the method definition (what you posted above) const, did you remember to change the method declaration as well?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me (i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)):

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

class ClassA
{
public:
  ClassA() { myList.push_back(1); myList.push_back(2); }
  bool MethodA(int x) const;
private:
  std::list<int> myList;
};

bool ClassA::MethodA(int x) const
{
  bool y = false;
  if(find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), x) != myList.end())
    {
      y = true;
    }
  return y;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  ClassA a;
  a.MethodA(5);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post a complete program which fails to compile. This compiles fine:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    std::list<int> ml;
    bool search(int x) const {
        return std::find(ml.begin(), ml.end(), x) != ml.end();
    }
};

int main() {
    const Foo f;
    std::cout << f.search(0) << "\n";
}
```

Maybe `find` isn't calling the function you think it is [Edit: more likely, silly me, myList isn't a `std::list`]. Cutting down to a small program which demonstrates the problem will probably reveal the cause, because at some point you'll remove something and it will start working.